# tkz-euclide InterLC error on getting intersection points

Tags: tkz-euclide

So via `tkz-euclide`, I wish to recreate this image

[image: This triangle]

With `AB = BC = CD = DE = EF`.

What I've done this far is this following MWE :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,tkz-base}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,15/0/G} % I use G since I thought AB is limited as a segment not a line or something else
\tkzDefPoint(18:3){B}
\tkzDrawCircle(B,A)
\tkzInterLC(A,G)(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{C}
\tkzDefCircle(C,B)
\tkzInterLC(A,C)(B,C) \tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzDefCircle(D,C)
\tkzInterLC(A,B)(C,D) \tkzGetPoint{E}
\tkzDefCircle(D,E)
\tkzInterLC(A,C)(D,E) \tkzGetPoint{F}
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,...,F)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error is that the code doesn't produce point `C`,`D`,`E` and `F` as in the image. Can anyone help me on this? Hopefully solved in `tkz-euclide` too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `tkz-euclide` package (sorry for the letters not be the same as in your example, I can guess you can fix it) :)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tkzSetUpPoint[size=2,color=black,fill=black]

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,7/0/B,1/2/C,3/-2/D}
    \tkzDefPointBy[rotation=center A angle 16](B)\tkzGetPoint{E}
    \tkzDefPointOnLine[pos=0.27](A,B)\tkzGetPoint{F}\tkzDrawPoints(F)
    \tkzMarkAngle[size=1.2](B,A,E)\tkzLabelAngle[pos=1.45](B,A,E){\scriptsize {$18^\circ$}}
    \tkzInterLC(A,E)(F,A)\tkzGetFirstPoint{G}\tkzDrawPoints(G)
    \tkzInterLC(A,B)(G,F)\tkzGetSecondPoint{H}\tkzDrawPoints(H)
    \tkzInterLC(A,E)(H,G)\tkzGetFirstPoint{I}\tkzDrawPoints(I)
    \tkzInterLC(A,B)(I,H)\tkzGetSecondPoint{J}\tkzDrawPoints(J)
    \tkzDrawSegments(A,B A,E F,G G,H H,I I,J B,J)
    \tkzMarkSegments[mark=|,size=1.2,very thin](A,F F,G G,H H,I I,J)
    \tkzLabelPoints[left](A){A}\tkzDrawPoint[](A)
    \tkzLabelPoints[above](G,I){G,I}
    \tkzLabelPoints(F,H,J){F,H,J}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: @Wilory Lu I realized a mistake in my code making the output slightly different from what you wanted. I just fixed it, please check it out.